# Can I Pass Out from Excessive Drinking?

Tags: bioshock

I've noticed that if I grab two or more alcoholic beverages in rapid succession, my sight gets wonky and blurry.  The length of time this effect lasts for seems to increase if I grab a larger number of bottles.  Is it possible to pass out, if enough alcoholic beverages are consumed in rapid succession?

Comment: ... and in the game!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, as the game has no concept of 'passing out' at all.

Comment: Actually, yeah - even when you die you just teleport to the nearest vita chamber...

Comment: Which begs the question: "Can you die from drinking too much?" (and yes I mean in the game).

Comment: I think it's pretty safe to assume that you can't, unless the game has an hidden parameter for "Alcohol percentage in your blood".

Comment: I wonder if you can die from smoking too much?  Cigarettes replenish a small amount of EVE, (magic, basically) but drain a small amount of HP.  This is worth looking into.

Comment: @GnomeSlice http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9974/will-smoking-too-much-kill-me

Comment: @danixd > Yes, that is **my** question.  I'm aware of it.  :P

Comment: @GnomeSlice ha sorry I didn't notice it was yours!