# Will smoking too much kill me?

Tags: bioshock

I've been mulling this over for a while now, and am unable to get all of the information I require to make an informed decision.  My **life** hinges on my decision, and I'd appreciate some input.

The thing is:
**I know smoking is bad for my health, but can I die because of it?**

---

*...now for some context*

Among the various "beneficial" (debatable) pickups in *BioShock*, is the pack of cigarettes.  Grabbing one of these replenishes a small amount of *EVE* (magic, basically), but drains a small amount of the player's health.

So, if I managed to get myself almost dead, and then smoked up, would this health drain kill me?

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and say "no", but without concrete evidence, I'm not sure that counts as an answer. I would imagine that it would not simply because you can grab alcohol (restores health at the expense of eve) with an empty eve bar to still restore health. It would serve to follow that grabbing a cigarette with an empty healthbar would likewise restore eve, but if the health's not there to lose, you won't lose it when you use them.

Comment: @Raven Dreamer I would like to point out that the case where you have an empty healthbar is in fact the definition of *dead*.

Comment: @Dfowj -- except that in bioshock specifically (and, admittedly, this is memory bias of the highest caliber), explosions and run-ins with big daddies have a habit of leaving me in a stunned, no-health-bar, you die if a butterfly lands on you state (until I hit "f" anyway). 'Course, I never have the chance to investigate the original question, because most instances the big-bad that nearly killed me manages to finish the job moments later.

Comment: Yes, you can. Not sure about the game though!

Comment: @Alan: too bad there's no Health StackExchange just yet, otherwise this question would have been much funnier, like [that other one](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4999/).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> On "Easy" and "Medium" difficulties, Jack will not die instantly from a fatal injury. Instead, his health will be reduced to one hit point, and will only die if he takes another hit in that state.
>
> <sub>[source](http://bioshock.wikia.com/wiki/Health)</sub>

This means that, unless you're playing on Hard mode, a package of cigarettes is not enough to kill you.

To die you'd have to:

1. Take more damage than you have health, thus sending you in this 1 HP almost dead state
2. Smoke a cigarette at *this* point.

You can die by merely smoking *only* if you're playing in Hard mode.

Comment: Oh hey, that explains my personal experiences!

Comment: @badp > So, even at 1 hp, you can't be killed by cigarettes on Easy or Normal difficulties?  Maybe it's just me, but I'm still not quite seeing a specific answer here.

Comment: @gnome aye, unless you were just brought to 1hp by some other effect.

Comment: @badp but I even mentioned that in my question, "if I managed to get myself almost dead".  So you're saying that it IS possible to die from smoking on any difficulty, as long as your health is brought very low beforehand?

Comment: @gnome, You'd need to 1. get more damage than you have HP for, get in this near-death state and 2. smoke your final cigarette.

Comment: @badp > But this is possible on every difficulty?

Comment: @gnome, there's no near-death state in Hard.

Comment: @badp > Now I'm confused.  If you need to be in the near-death state to be killed by smoking, then you should be able to be killed on every difficulty **but** hard, correct?  This is not what it says in your answer.

Comment: @Gnome What badp is trying to say is this. Lets say you have 10 HP left and smoking takes off 15 HP. On Easy/Normal difficulty, if you smoke a cigarette, you will not die, but instead you will be reduced to 1 HP. If you then smoke AGAIN, you will die. However, on Hard difficulty, that first cigarette (when you were sitting at 10 HP) would kill you outright and you would not get the leniency of a 1 HP last-chance buffer.

Comment: @TheQ > So it IS possible to die as a result of smoking on any difficulty.  That's all I was looking for.  If @badp edits that into his answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @Gnome That's exactly what I said to be honest: «a package of cigarettes is not enough to kill you. You'd need to smoke right after being knocked down to 1 hp.»

Comment: @badp I figured an example would help is all, to differentiate between each difficulty. I understood it but I can see where there might be some confusion.

Comment: @TheQ, fair enough. I'll try and clarify.

Comment: @badp > So, after being knocked down to 1 hp, a pack of cigarettes IS enough to kill you.  I even speculated on this specifically in my question.

Comment: @GnomeSlice I thought you meant "I have 20 hp, take 19 damage and now only have 1 hp. Now I smoke, what happens?" -- then what happens is you go to the almost dead state (except for Hard). If you meant "I have 20 hp, take 30 damage and now I smoke, what happens?" -- then you die.

Comment: @badp > Sorry for the miscommunication.  That is in fact what I meant by 'almost dead'.

Comment: So... to translate this into real life: If I smoke cigarettes excessively, I can avoid lung cancer by wrapping gauze around myself and applying Neosporin? Understood.