# How can I tell if I am drunk and how long will this last?

Tags: achievements, bioshock-infinite

Per the Lost Weekend achievement, I need to kill 5 enemies while I am drunk.   I *think* I am drunk after a few alcoholic beverages and my vision starts to shake / blur (in bioshock infinite remember...), but roughly how long does this last or how soon after becoming drunk do I have to kill someone for it to apply for that achievement ?

Comment: I approve of this question in spirit. Or is that on spirits?

Comment: Possibly relevant: [Can I pass out from excessive drinking](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/9768/336)

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jlDNnp9Oi7c

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After consuming alcoholic beverages your screen becomes blurry, it is only while the screen is blurry that kills count towards this Achievement (~5-10 seconds). The best place to get this is when you first arrive in Shantytown, there is a bar at the bottom left. Elizabeth will make a comment that you could either go to the bar or go on with the quest. As soon as you enter the bar you will see the autosave icon display. In here there is plenty of alcohol you can consume and killing any of the NPC's will count towards the Achievement. If you run out of NPC's or out of Alcohol you can reload and repeat the process until the achievement pops.

Comment: It is also worth noting, that you can only get drunk by drinking 3 bottles of alcoholic beverage in relatively quick succession (about 3 seconds in between two bottles). There are a few rare bottles that make you drunk instantly, one of which can be found in said bar in Shantytown.